# Works in shell but not as a program?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried the following in the shell

```
infile = open("studentinfo.txt", "r")
infile.read()
```

And it returned the text in the file, which is what I want it to do. However, when I wrote it and saved it as a program

```
def main():
    infile = open("studentinfo.txt", "r")
    infile.read()
main()
```

It just returned blank lines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your function never *returns* the values, so they are discarded again.

Add a `return` statement:

```
def main():
    infile = open("studentinfo.txt", "r")
    return infile.read()
```

Also, in the interactive interpreter, all expression results are *echoed* automatically unless the result is `None`. In regular scripts, you'll have to print results explicitly:

```
print(main())
```

Comment: Minor nitpicking: Shouldn't the `print` rather be _inside_ the `main` function? I mean, by convention the `main` should not return anything, right?

Comment: @tobias_k: that depends on whom you ask; it is at best a convention. I did want to separate out function behaviour from the interpreter behaviour.